# Connect Wear OS emulator to iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, wear-os

Is it possible to connect the Wear OS emulator from Android Studio to an iPhone?

I would like to make sure that everything works fine on iPhones too.

Comment: iPhone is the mobile version of MAC OS and Android Studio is working there as what the [documentation(Run apps on a hardware device)](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device) stated. But if you meant that running Android Apps in iPhone, I think it is not possible.

Comment: I don't mean running Android apps on iPhone. Using Android Studio, you can run Android apps on an WearOS emulator. Since WearOS can sync with a phone, you can actually bind the emulator to your physical Android phone. I would like to bind the emulator to my physical iPhone instead.

Comment: I think what your trying to ask is it is possible to pair the Wear OS emulator with an iphone via bluetooth... id just like to find out if its possible to pair a Wear OS emulator with an iPhone and Android phone... there are a number of old posts how to pair with Android prior to Wear OS 2.0 but none work for me.

Comment: Yes, that's the question